# AngularJS: Send data to database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, angularjs-scope

I'm pretty new to angular and currently I have some statistics in multiple tables that I would like to send to my database.  I display my tables' information like so:

**index.html**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="complete in completed track by $index">
        <td>{{complete[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{complete[1]}}</td>
    </tr>

<table class="wrapper text-center">
    <tr ng-repeat="board in boards track by $index">
        <td>{{board[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{board[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{board[2]}}</td> 
        <td>{{board[3]}}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="wrapper text-center">
    <tr ng-repeat="cell_line in cell_lines track by $index">
        <td >
            {{cell_line[0]}}
        </td>
        <td >
            {{cell_line[1]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to be able to send the data stored in `$scope.completed`,  `$scope.boards`, and `$scope.cell_lines` to a function, but those variables are out of scope once I exit the `ng-repeat`.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="postToDatabase(dataXYZ)">Send to Databse</button>
```

**Question:** Is there some way to send this data from outside the tables?

Comment: Not sure if they are out of scope, show us the markup where the table and the function being called are. But you always can access those data though the controller.

Comment: You can create global scope variables to store those data and use them globally.

Comment: Can you post a plnkr with an example? From what you've described it doesn't seem like those values should be out of scope.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. You are not editing the elements, so you have access to $scope.completed, $scope.boards and $scope.cell_lines ... In the controller, you just have to make an AJAX call with a copy of $scope.completed etc... via JSON.parse(angular.toJson($scope.completed)); etc... (to remove the $$ keys added by angular)

Comment: You are correct.  I was able to access the variables in the controller but I thought they needed to be passed to the function.